# How secure is a Laravel signed route?

Tags: laravel

In my application, i generate purchase orders. To avoid send the pdf by mail, I'm sending a signed route link.

How secure is this link? Is there a possibility, that someone can hack it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Laravel` signed route, is reliant on a signature hash done with the hmac `sha256` approach.

`UrlGenerator.php` in `Laravel` has this [code](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/08dcce48e0e295b4ce79fcf5b53ad34320ff4eed/UrlGenerator.php#L340) that generates it.

```
return $this->route($name, $parameters + [
    'signature' => hash_hmac('sha256', $this->route($name, $parameters, $absolute), $key),
], $absolute);
```

This is as far as i know considered secure, related [crypto stack site post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35835/how-secure-is-hmac-sha256). As long as your application key remains uncompromised, which it should.